# How do I remove a Google Charts Calendar legend?

Tags: javascript, charts, calendar

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

Is there a way to remove the legend (top right gradient that shows min and max values) from a Google Calendar chart?

Answer (score 1):

just set the legend parameter to none

```
legend: 'none';
```

from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

> An object with members to configure various aspects of the legend, or 'none', if no legend should appear.

Comment: Using the current build (44, I believe) this doesn't work for me.  I've tried both "legend: 'none'" and "legend: { 'position': 'none' }" - neither seemed to make a difference.